# Issue with Unity Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am working on ASP.NET Web Forms app based on Unity.

I register a class with Unity called "VBCRepository" that implements "IVBCRepository". I mapped IVBCRepository to VBCRepository in Unity through Web.config file.

The VBCRepository inherits from a VBCRepositoryBase class that in tern implements the IVBCRepository and defines a property "Session". The Session object has a State property {Active and Closed}

At one moment of time the Session.State is Closed, while it shouldnt be like that because the code is not changing it. If not changed manually, the only reason to make it Closed is if the object goes out of scope.

When I placed the Session property on VBCRepository I am not facing this problem anymore. Could it be because of the Base class?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. You might try adding some code. That might help.